# Read properties file in GWT UI Binder class

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a website where a text is hard coded right now.
I want the text to be picked up from a properties file now.

```
<c:info>
                    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="info">
                        <c:InfoItem>
                        We should only remarket every 3 years unless agreed with Placement team otherwise, as per &lt;a href="http://ke.aon.com.au/aon_risk_solutions/products_and_facilities/middle_market_business/what_is_new.asp#p3">Remarketing rules on the KE&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;br/&gt;
                        A minimum of 4 insurers should be selected when remarketing, up to a maximum of 7. &lt;br/&gt;
                        &lt;br/&gt;                 
                        Deselection reasons:&lt;br/&gt;
                        • Renewing with existing Vertex Insurer (this would be used for Vertex renewals and would be the default for non-holding Insurers)&lt;br/&gt;
                        • Agreement reached outside platform by Placement team (used where open market business is negotiated prior to placement on the platform)&lt;br/&gt;
                        </c:InfoItem>
                    </g:HTMLPanel>
                </c:info>
```

InfoItem is a Ui Binder class . I want this text to be read from the properties file.

Comment: What is an `InfoItem`? Why not add a key attribute to that element and use it to lookup in the properties and emit the desired markup?

Comment: Thats what I actually want to do... But I am not sure how to read a properties file in GWT client package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might interested in [GWT I18](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html) package.

Read more about [GWT DevGuide UiBinder I18n](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n.html) where it is explained in detail along with samples.

Read more about [GWT DevGuide I18n Constants](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants.html#ConstantsProperties)

Comment: Hey Thanks Braj... Reading the properties from the Constant properties file worked for me!!! Thanks